# Why is vsnprintf Not Writing the Same Number of Characters as strncpy Would?

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions, string-length, strncpy

I've asked [the same question about `strncpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54132563/2642059), but there the `string` ends up containing the whole input string. When passing a string to `vsnprintf` the last character always gets chopped off: https://rextester.com/UIQMX91570

For simplicity I've also included the live example link above inline in the code:

```
void bar(const char* format, va_list vlist) {
    const auto buf_size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0U, format, vlist);
    string buffer(buf_size, '\0');

    vsnprintf(data(buffer), buf_size, format, vlist);
    cout << data(buffer) << endl;
}

void foo(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list vlist;

    va_start(vlist, format);
    bar(format, vlist);
    va_end(vlist);
}
```

If I call this with: `foo("lorem ipsum %d", 13)` the output I get is:

> lorem ipsum 1

Where as I would have expected: lorem ipsum 13

Can anyone explain the discrepancy? When I debug I get a `buf_size` of 14 which *should* be enough to contain the entire string, yet it does not :(

Comment: To paraphrase the answers, for the benefit of `strncpy` fans: `strncpy` can produce an invalid C string (with no nul terminator); `vsnprintf` cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the discrepancy?

Because their documented behavior is different.

[`strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

> If count is reached before the entire array src was copied, the resulting character array **is not null-terminated**.

but [`vsnprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf)

> At most buf_size-1 characters are written. **The resulting character string will be terminated with a null character, unless buf_size is zero.**

emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 4):

Because man page clearly says that

> If the output was truncated due to this limit then  the  return  value is the number of characters (not including the trailing '\0') which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available.

If you'd check the return value of your second `vsnprintf` call, you'd see that return value is equal to the size, as in the man page:

> Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was
>   truncated.

Answer (score 1):

The `buf_size` parameter to `vsnprintf` specifies how many characters to write, ***including*** the terminating NUL character.  The return value is the number of characters produced, ***not including*** the terminating NUL character.

You want

```
const auto buf_size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0U, format, vlist) + 1;
```